# count of odd elements of left side and right side please modify my code without exceeding the time limit

Tags: java

> My code is O(n^2), please to decrease as O(n).
> My question is count of the left side odd numbers and right side odd numbers. If it is equal on the bothsides(left and right) then print the respecive element other wise print the "-1". my code logic was correct it executing the normal text cases, but it was failing to execute the large value of text cases.It shows the error as "time exceeded".It was exceeding the timelimit of the compiler.i want to decrease the time limit of my code.
>
> example: my input is 4  1 4 3 8  and my output:-1 4 -1 -1
>
> example 2: my input is 6 1 3 4 8 5 7  and my output: -1 -1 4 8 -1 -1

enter code here

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = s.nextInt();

    int temp = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    int a[] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = a[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (a[j] % 2 != 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int k = i + 1; k < n; k++) {

            if (a[k] % 2 != 0) {
                flag++;
            }
        }
        if (count == flag) {

            System.out.print(temp + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("-1 ");
        }
        count = 0;
        flag = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Might want to properly format your code to make it easier for readers to understand what your algorithm is doing. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Also, what is your question, and what values are you entering?

Comment: Sir, i was modified my code.

Comment: Please format your code **properly**

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it yet but it should work.

Your algorithm is O(n^2) and this one is O(n).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=s.nextInt();

    int a[]=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        a[i]=s.nextInt();
    }

    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
      if(a[j]%2!=0) {
            total++;
      }
    }

    int leftTotal = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        int k = a[i];
        if (k%2!=0) {
            leftTotal++;
        }
      if (leftTotal = (total-leftTotal)) {
        System.out.println(k);
      } else {
        System.out.println(k);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir, it is not working. it is workin for only one test case.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Your Code Here
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=s.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n],flag=0,count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            a[i]=s.nextInt();
            if(a[i]%2!=0)
            count++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if(a[i]%2!=0)
            count--;
            if(flag==count)
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
            else
            System.out.print("-1 ");
            if(a[i]%2!=0)
            flag++;
        }

    }
}
```